# Regex to match everything from nth occurence of character onwards

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to create a regex that matches from the second '|' character onwards.
The match from a string like this 'i:0#.f|membership|msol-svc@xyz.com' should be 'msol-svc@xyz.com'.

I tried `(?<=').*$` but this matches from the first occurrence of '|'.
At least the positive lookbehind excludes '|' from the match.
However, I would need to ensure that this starts from the 2nd occurrence of '|'.

https://regex101.com/r/Dr7ly2/9

In addition, I was able to accomplish the match using capture groups but I'm not sure if this is the smartest way of doing it.

`(.*\|)(.*)`

https://regex101.com/r/Dr7ly2/10

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using PCRE regex engine? Try [`^(?:[^|]*\|){2}\K.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/Dr7ly2/11) Else, capture that part into a capturing group using [`^(?:[^|]*\|){2}(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/Dr7ly2/12). What is the environment you are using the regex in?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew or `(?:.*?\|){2}`?

Comment: Planning to use the regex in PowerShell.

Comment: @Bohemian Your regex selects the opposite of what I'm trying to match. https://regex101.com/r/Dr7ly2/13

Comment: @colonel_claypoo I was suggesting a simplification to the start of Wiktor's regex

Comment: @Bohemian ah, gotcha! Both work fine, thank you.